# extracting existing dataframe to dataframe array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have an original dataframe read as df. I want to separate the df to several parts and each one saved to a individual csv.
my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')

for i in range(1, 10):
        df[i] = df.iloc[257*(i-1):256+257*(i-1), : ].copy()
        df[i].to_csv('%d.csv' % i, index=None, header = False)
```

but it gave me error as:

```
line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\Yu-chengHsiao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
   packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3826, in _set_item
    loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Yu-chengHsiao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
   packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
        raise KeyError(key) from err
    KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

anyone know how I could solve it?

Comment: Which criteria should the DataFrame be split with? Your "calculation" for indexing is quite confusing to me.

Comment: If my answer was what you were looking for could you mark it as answered? :) that way this thread will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')

for i in range(1, 10):
    df.iloc[257*(i-1):256+257*(i-1), : ].to_csv(f'{i}.csv', index=None, header = False)
```

This should work. No need to copy the splitted dataframe to a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given above but it's good to understand what your code did. With df[i], you can create or set a column called i with some value, in this case a large dataframe.

If you want to save a section of the dataframe, you can first create a dictionary, for example dfs = dict(). Then you can set a section of the df to dfs[i].